# How to use a tag with incomplete url for redirect to external website?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I use this code,

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">test</a>
```

when i click `test link` it's will be redirect to `stackoverflow.com` work good.

But when i use this code

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com">test</a>
```

It's will be redirect to `example.com/stackoverflow.com`

I want to know how can redirect to `stackoverflow.com` with tihs code

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com">test</a>
```

Comment: its not passible by just html, and there is no reason in doing this

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the link.

Possible values:

An absolute URL - points to another web site (like href="http://www.example.com/default.htm")
A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like href="default.htm")

Link to an element with a specified id within the page (like href="#top")

Other protocols (like https://, ftp://, mailto:, file:, etc..)

A script (like href="javascript:alert('Hello');")

You have to add prefix

> https://